In CMBR anisotropy experiments like Boomerang, how do we know the true spacing of hot spots in the CMB?
I can't imagine that this isn't a duplicate, but I can't find it. A link to an existing answer would be a sufficient reply.
If the universe was positively curved, the hot spots would appear closer together because that's what you'd expect from a concave surface.

But how do we know what the flat, undistorted CMB looks like if we've only seen it curved?
The articles I found online all talk about the appearance of triangles on a curved surface, but they don't explain how we know what the non-curved surface looks like.

Here are some videos you might find interesting. From Don Lincoln, an overview if the CMB and what we can learn from it - Secrets of the Cosmic Microwave Background. From PBS Space Time, Baryon Acoustic Oscillations - Sound Waves from the Beginning of Time and Secrets of the Cosmic Microwave Background

@mmesser314 thanx I'm there. Ima figure this out!

The statistics of hot and cold spots on the CMB can be computed given a cosmological model. By "statistics", to zeroth order I mean the power spectrum, which is much easier to interpret than the map itself. The power spectrum is a prediction of the cosmological model, whereas the map itself is a combination of the power spectrum plus random fluctuations that cannot be predicted.
Since we can map a given cosmological model to an expected power spectrum, we can compare the observed power spectrum to the predictions of many different models, and see which models fit the observations well. Models with a significant amount of spatial curvature do a poor job reproducing the observed power spectrum, whereas a spatially flat model does fit it well.
In particular, the position of the first peak in the power spectrum is related to the spatial curvature. There is more explanation and a cool visualization in Wayne Hu's tutorial here: https://background.uchicago.edu/~whu/intermediate/clcurvature.html
Since this is a possible source of confusion, I'll also just mention that when people say the Universe is spatially flat or has positive or negative curvature, they mean the three-dimensional space we live in may or may not have curvature, even though the figures you posted show two dimensional surfaces. The two dimensional surfaces in the figure are just cartoons. The fact that we can think of the CMB as living on the inside of a sphere is not relevant for the curvature of the Universe -- that "sphere" or "surface" of last scattering where the CMB was formed is present because that is the set of points where light rays emitted from that time will reach us today. The more subtle three dimensional curvature of space imprints itself on the pattern of the hot and cold spots, specifically through the location of the first peak in the power spectrum as described above.

Ok thank you. Winning answer. There seems to be a lot of ad hoc assumptions, like, "we assume that there is a form of dark energy in a cosmological constant that makes the universe flat despite a sub-critical density of matter" and assumptions about the propagation of sound waves in the primordial plasma. That's outrageous. I assumed they had some kind of hard evidence, analogous to parallax  or the Hubble relation. I can't see this as anything other than fantastic speculation. Yet they believe that the universe is flat with such accuracy. Oh well. TY.

@MissUnderstands There is a lot of hard evidence. I didn't go into detail in this short stack exchange answer but the tutorials I linked to by Wayne Hu describe the evidence in quite a bit of depth.

the University of Chicago stuff? that's what I was reading ehen I wrote that comment. That's where the quote about "a form of dark energy and a cosmological..." came from.

@MissUnderstands I mean, that is a student level tutorial given as an introduction to an enormous body of research literature, so no I don't mean that one website has all the evidence in favor of the standard cosmological model. But his website does has a lot of excellent pedagogical overviews. I'm not sure what your exact issue is, but you should perhaps consider that you may have things to learn before dismissing an entire field of study. Or not, I guess, but no one is going to care that you personally think the state of the field is "outrageous" based on skimming a couple of tutorials.

@Andrew Part of the issue, I believe, that Miss Understands and others have is that the field of cosmology presents itself as one of the least scientific of the STEM fields. There are a lot of assumptions made with a great number discoveries being claimed off of the backs of these assumptions. In a sense, the news media respects criminals more than cosmologists respect their own work. News media will refer to the crimes as alleged until its proven, where as cosmology has been talking about Dark Matter and what it does for years. Dark Matter may still be unicorn farts for what we know.

@DavidS If you are fed up with popular news level coverage of science (which I am as well!), and you also have a genuine interest in cosmology and don't just like writing smug comments on the internet, then perhaps you would be interested in studying a real scientific text that focuses on substance over hype, such as Barbara Ryden's textbook: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Cosmology-Barbara-Ryden/dp/1107154839, or at a higher level, Peebles's textbook: https://www.amazon.com/Principles-Physical-Cosmology-Phillip-Peebles/dp/0691019339

However, if you don't want to put in the work to learn the subject seriously and understand what the actual scientific claims and evidence are surrounding, eg, dark matter, then maybe consider that you cannot get an accurate representation from reading the popular press, and that you might not be in a position to judge the scientific merits of an entire field.

Sigh you're both so confident. Sure, dark matter could be unicorn farts, if you could come up with a mathematically precise model of unicorn farts consistent with our current understanding of fundamental physics that you could show quantitatively reproduces the expansion history of the Universe as observed in supernova, CMB, BAO, lensing ..., as well as galaxy rotation curves. I'll be the first to admit that we don't know what dark matter is, but something is responsible for the observations. I just feel your attitudes are pretty dismissive and not showing you're trying to learn.

It's true that there is a lot we don't know in cosmology, but we do know some things, and calling the whole field "outrageous" or "unicorn farts" is throwing the baby out with the baby water and it's very frustrating to hear that attitude after spending time to write an answer.

It is precisely because the spatial curvature of the universe influences the apparent angular separation of those spots that makes that particular measurement so useful.
I don't think the discussion of "surfaces" is the right analogy, it's more like a magnification scale relating the physical size of the perturbations to their angular size in our observations.
It turns out that given the physics of how the hot and cold fluctuations form, their angular separation is chiefly determined by the total energy densities in the universe and hence how close it is to being spatially flat.
